# gforth 2constant; explanation of the content?

Tags: forth, gforth

in gforth, when I want to see the inner of the word `2constant` , I use the command

```
see 2constant
```

then the output is..

```
: 2Constant  
  Create 2, 140549207084808 (does>2) ;
```

I could not find so far a clear explanation after "`2,`". I am a beginner in forth and need to understand this, in order to migrate the word `2constant` in a board, which forth has no `2constant` word. Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

If I didn't have `2CONSTANT` defined I'd define:

```
: my2constant    \ d <name> --
  CREATE 2, DOES> 2@ ;
```

In GFORTH:

```
see 2CONSTANT 
: 2Constant  
  Create 2, 140453810216712 (does>2) ; ok
see my2CONSTANT 
: my2constant  
  Create 2, 140453810521432 (does>2) ; ok
HERE .      140453810521464  ok
\ the constant seems related to the dictionary pointer when the word is defined.
\ I'd guess the number is related to the code address which `(does>2)` executes 
\ when an instance of 2CONSTANT is executed. 

\ The words defined by 2CONSTANT match the original definition
123 456 my2constant test  ok
test . .  456 123  ok
see test 
create test  
DOES> 2@ ; ok 

123 456 2CONSTANT testg  ok

see testg 
create testg  
DOES> 2@ ; ok
```

**Added following the comment**

```
: 2,  , , ; \ d -- ; Place d into the dictionary.

: 2@  DUP CELL+ @ SWAP @ ;  \ a -- lo hi ;  

: 2CONSTANT   \ d <name> -- ; Create a 2constant with the name <name>
              \ does> -- d
  CREATE 2, DOES> 2@ ;

\ For completeness 
: 2!  SWAP OVER ! CELL+ ! ;  \ lo hi a -- ;  a contains hi a +cell contains lo

: 2VARIABLE   \ <name> -- ; Create a double variable in the dictionary
              \ does> -- a
  CREATE 0 , 0 , DOES> ;
```

Testing

```
123 456 2CONSTANT test  ok
test .s <2> 123 456  ok

2VARIABLE vtest  ok
789 1011 vtest 2! .S <2> 123 456  ok
vtest 2@ .S <4> 123 456 789 1011  ok
```

I can't make sense of the code in the comment.  It almost does 2! but would overwrite the first value stored with the second.  I can't see why the compilation state is relevant.

```
: G_2CONSTANT   \ lo hi addr -- ; Assumed to make it do something
  DUP >R                    \ lo hi addr r: addr
  STATE @ IF 0 , 0 , THEN   \ Why ?
  R>                        \ lo hi addr addr
  !                         \ lo hi  ; Store addr at addr ?
  ! ;                       \ Store lo at hi.  Causes the error

: G_CONSTANT   \ lo hi addr -- ; Equivalent to 2!
  DUP >R ! R> CELL+ ! ;
```

CREATE is required if 2CONSTANT is to define a new word and the DOES> action of the word is required to recover the stored values.

Comment: I dont have 2, and 2@ in my (old) Forth. ChatGPT said it should work.. but not..  : G_2CONSTANT 
    DUP >R STATE @ IF 0 , 0 , THEN R> ! ! ;  then a try with "14  15  G_2CONSTANT  TATA" gave :28: Invalid memory address
14  15  >>>G_2CONSTANT<<<  TATA
Backtrace:
$7F94F424B548 !

Comment: Thanks. I am moving/learning. I just realized my Forth has no CELL+ therefore this is where I will look at now (I am overtaking all 2CONSTANT 2, 2@ )

Comment: CELL+ seems to be 5+ in my Forth anno 1984

Comment: From 1984 I'd expect `2+`, 16 bits!  `5+` doesn't feel right.  What does ` HERE 0 , HERE SWAP - . ` print? That will be the cell size.

Comment: Try a web search for 'Starting Forth' by Leo Brodie.  The .pdf version is a copy of the 1981 edition.  It's likely the glossary and word definitions reflect your 1984 Forth better than a more modern system like GForth.  It may help.

Comment: Comment to the last 2 posts. "HERE 0 , HERE SWAP - ." result is 5 at the screen. I got a  'Starting Forth' by Leo Brodie by eBay (I am reading).

Comment: Does defining a word `: CELL+ 5 + ; ` on your Forth implementation make the `2CONSTANT` definition work correctly?

Comment: : 2@  DUP 5+ @ SWAP @ ;  and  : 2CONSTANT  CREATE , , DOES> 2@ ; tested with BL BL 2CONSTANT EMPTY seems to give the correct result (S. give [ 32 32 ] ok { 2 } ) therefore no need for CELL+ so far. I will update the question with this when deeper tested/confirmed.

Comment: The advantage of `CELL+` is that it explains why the code is adding 5 to an address.  Also code written for a 32 bit processor can run on a 64 one with only a change to `CELL+`, or on a 20 bit processor as `: cell+ 5 + ;`.

Comment: Ouch.. 123 456 2CONSTANT TEST  ok   TEST .S  <2> 456 123 ok   which is different from above. But then . 456  ok  and  . 123  ok .  So it should be ok. if not, comments are welcome.

Comment: The gforth `.S` prints with the top of stack on the right.  Which is the same order as the typed entry.  It appears your `.S` prints the top of stack on the left.  So assuming your `.S` does put TOS at the left it appears to work. If `123 456 .S` shows `456 123` it looks good.